# Where does Postman install to?

Tags: windows-7, installation, postman

I recently installed [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) on my Windows 7 laptop. Postman launched automatically once the initial installation finished, but I haven't been able to figure out how to re-launch the application since then.

The installer didn't give me the option to select my install location or add a desktop shortcut. I've searched `C:\Program Files`, but I didn't see any folder for Postman.

Where does Postman install to on Windows?

Comment: I don't have experience with postman, but this kind of installation usually installs per user, and as such, you probably can find it in `%appdata%\Postman` or another folder within %appdata%. (you can type %appdata% directly in the explorer addressbar, but if you want to navigate to it, its c:\users\username\appdata\roaming)

Comment: Isn't Postman a Chrome Extension? can you get to it via the Chrome "Apps" button? (Ive never used or installed it though)

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft click the link in the question and you can figure out the answer yourself: aka, no it is not.

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft I am using the native app. [Postman's Chrome App is no longer supported as of March 2017](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/03/14/going-native/).

Comment: @LPChip Your hunch was correct. It installed to ``C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Postman\``

Comment: You're welcome. :) Normally it is courtesy to ask the person who made a comment to post an answer so you can award them. Given that I have plenty of reputation and I don't really need it, I'm fine to keep it as it is currently. But next time, maybe you'll want to ask for an aswer instead. :)

Comment: @LPChip My apologies. I wrote the answer so I could include information about the Squirrel Installer, but I should have asked first. I will make sure to do so in the future.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I forgive you. :) Just remember it for a next time. Its not so much about providing extra information, but more a gesture of giving a thank you for helping me. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**On Windows, Postman installs to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Postman`.**

- As a shortcut, you can enter `%LocalAppData%\Postman`.
- The main Postman executable is stored in a subfolder `\app-5.x.x`

  - (Replace `x` with app version)

There are two likely reasons why Postman installs to `%AppData%`

- The `%AppData%` folder is per-user, allowing installation without administrator rights
- Postman seems to use the Squirrel Installer, which [doesn't allow custom install directories](https://twitter.com/discordapp/status/843624938674311168)

  - (Noted by the presence of `\Postman\app-5.x.x\SquirrelSetup.log`)

---

[Thanks to LPChip](https://superuser.com/questions/1268614/where-does-postman-install-to?noredirect=1#comment1869274_1268614) for suggesting `%AppData%` as a possible install location.

Comment: Hi @Stevoisiak, do you know how to launch postman using the Windows Run Command? So i press Windows button + R, the Run Command appears, how do i launch Postman from there ? If i type `Postman`, a Windows Explorer will open, sending me to C:\Users\<username>\Postman\files

Answer (score 1):

The Postman native application is installed by default in %LocalAppData%\Postman. The reason for using this location might be that administrator privileges are not required to access this folder.

Comment: Hi @AntonioSergioFerraz, do you know how to launch postman using the Windows Run Command? So i press Windows button + R, the Run Command appears, how do i launch Postman from there ? If i type Postman, a Windows Explorer will open, sending me to C:\Users\<username>\Postman\files

Answer (score 1):

The following is an ***addition*** to the couple of excellent answers found in this post
as it helped me and i would be happy if it helped someone.

**Objective:**
If you are like me and you are looking to launch `Postman` from the `Run command prompt`(*Windows + R* keys), read on.

---

One of the places that the `Run command prompt` will pick up commands is from the `Path` environment variable. So i modified the `Path` environment variable and added: 
`C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Postman`

Now i can *Windows + R*, enter *Postman* in the prompt et voila!

**Note**: If another location opens up, like for me
`C:\Users\<Username>\Postman\files`

> Delete that location, if you are not using it.

**Bonus:**
To find out more about how & where the `Run command prompt` is resolving its command, you may want to read [this excellent post](https://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/111232)

Cheers